# Server 2008 Filesharing: One login for multiple Users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, network-share

We are running a media server on Server 2008.  I am trying to setup one of the shares to accessed through one username & password, for reasons specific to the environment--It cannot be anonymous, but also can't be authenticated through AD; hence, one username/password for multiple users.

I have tried to set it up as described above, but not sure the best way.  Should I setup the User on the local machine, or as an AD User?  I also can't seem to get the permissions set right.

Any help or resources that you could provide would be much appreciated!

Thanks-

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can't be authenticated through AD, just create a new user on the local machine through computer management and then set the permissions on the folder you want to share to give access to that local user, you will need to select the local computer instead of the domain (assuming its joined to a domain) under the add new user for security settings.

Users will access using the the username: MACHINENAME\username  where machinename is the name of that local machine and the username is the user you create on that local machine.